# Blank line between equation and theorem statement

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, bookmarks, debugging, thmtools

I need to end a paragraph with an equation before the statement of a theorem, but I get an unnecessary blank line. How can I remove it? Looks like the problem lies within the "thmtools" and "bookmark" packages. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[open]{bookmark}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{teorema}

\begin{document}
 Equation:
 \[
  a^2+b^2=c^2
 \]
 \begin{teorema}
  Content of the theorem.
 \end{teorema}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `hyperref`, rather than with `bookmarks` (and `thmtools` is not involved at all).

The fact that `hyperref` wants to set an anchor for the theorem label has the unwanted consequence that TeX thinks that the equation is followed by some text belonging to the same paragraph.

Simple solution: *always* leave a blank line in front of `\begin{teorema}`. Your code will also be cleaner and more readable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[open]{bookmark}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{teorema}

\begin{document}

Equation:
\[
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\]

\begin{teorema}
Content of the theorem.
\end{teorema}

\end{document}
```

[image]